# How to access $logs container in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have enabled logging for my Azure Blob Storage account per Microsoft Documentation (link below), but the $logs container where this data is stored doesn't seem to be visible on the Azure Portal. However, I can see it from Azure Storage Explorer desktop application. I've tried looking for some sort of setting that would allow me to see it in the standard portal, but no luck. Is this not possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The diagnostics logs are saved in a blob container named `$logs` in your storage account. You can view the log data using a storage explorer like the Microsoft Storage Explorer, or programmatically using the storage client library or PowerShell.

The following PowerShell snippet is an example of filtering the list of log blobs by name to specify a time, and by metadata to identify just those logs that contain write operations.

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container '$logs' |  
Where-Object {  
    $_.Name -match 'table/2014/05/21/05' -and   
    $_.ICloudBlob.Metadata.LogType -match 'write'  
} |  
ForEach-Object {  
    "{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}" –f $_.Name,   
    $_.ICloudBlob.Metadata.StartTime,   
    $_.ICloudBlob.Metadata.EndTime,   
    $_.ICloudBlob.Metadata.LogType  
}
```

The following is a sample URI that can be used to access the log:

```
https://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/$logs/blob/2011/07/31/1800/000001.log
```

For information about listing blobs programmatically, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging?tabs=dotnet#how-logs-are-stored).

Comment: Hi Joey, so just to confirm is there no way of making it visible on the standard portal? Do you know the best way of managing access to this container without the portal?

Comment: As I have said, you can not see it in portal but you can view the log from storage explorer or powershell or programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using $logs container, you can create your own blob storage container and configure your service to log to it.

1. Create a blob container inside a storage account (perhaps name is something like myapplogs, where myapp is the name of your app service).
2. Add a role to the blob container (e.g., Blob Container->Access Control->Add->Add Role Assignment->select app service's managed identity and the Storage Blob Data Contributor role).
3. For an Azure App Service, under Monitoring->AppService Logs, enable Application Logging (blob) and then click the link for storage containers (if it is set to $logs still click the link to change this setting) and select your storage account and then the blob container that you created in step 1 above.  The app will then log to this container and you can view the log files and download them to view the logs all through the Azure portal.